# What does the visitLocalVariable() method of the MethodVisitor class in the ASM bytecode engineering library do?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, .class-file

I am using ASM (for the first time) in an application to create Java class files. This is for the backend of a compiler I am writing.

I read the relevant parts of the ASM documentation and have a question about stack map frames. ASM says it can automatically compute those frames if the class writer is initialized with the appropriate flags. My question is, does that mean I will not ever have to call the visitLocalVariable() method on the method visitors myself? I am not sure what that method does. The documentation does say that I do not need to call the visitFrame() method if frames are computed automatically, but it is silent on the visitLocalVariable() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`visitLocalVariable()` describes or defines the *debug* information as stored in the [`LocalVariableTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13) and [`LocalVariableTypeTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.14) attributes of a `Code` attribute. They are not required for normal operation and distinct from the information stored in a `StackMapTable`.

In other words, unless you want to provide debug information, you never need to call `visitLocalVariable()`, regardless of whether stack map frames are automatically computed or not.

---

Note the differences of the information stored within these attributes. `LocalVariable[Type]Table` stores names and [generic] types of local variables and their scope regarding the source level language. `StackMapTable` stores type information for local variables and operand stack entries regarding the JVM type system for the byte code verifier.